# Error 'Render ring head forced to zero'

Tags: startup

I have encountered this error message quite a few times now, usually at startup: `*ERROR* render ring head forced to zero`.  It doesn't actually seem to affect anything, in my experience.  I was just curious about what the message means.

Comment: it's a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/660405 If you are member of launchpad please join the "I am affected by this"! If not please consider to join :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Rinzwind in the comments, it's [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/660405). Please mark yourself as affected. If you're not a member of launchpad, then please join launchpad and then mark yourself as being affected.

Comment: I have done.  It just seems weird that it didn't seem to affect startup at all.